# Detect physical machine, as opposed to detecting a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, wmi, hyper-v

Hypervisor presence can be detected via WMI like this;

```
select * from Win32_ComputerSystem
```

From that, read `HypervisorPresent` and if true, then it is present.

Equivalent VMIC command:

```
ComputerSystem get HypervisorPresent
```

This gives "true" for systems running under VMWare and VirtualBox and Hyper-V.

The problem is that it also gives "true", when run on physical machines when Hyper-V is installed, i.e. outside of a virtualized system.

So, my question is this:

Is it somehow possible to detect if the system is an actual physical machine even when Hyper-V is installed?

I had an idea of also checking if the Hyper-V service/role is installed, but that isn't enough since you can do nested virtualization with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

Check the “HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Auto” mostly all the host details stored in this key at guest

Using HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters you get more information about it

but only works for HyperV you need to validate twice one time for other hypervisors and second time for HyperV.

There is an class [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850169(v=vs.85).aspx.) to share vm and host details.

You can [Check this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/219.hyper-v-how-to-find-the-host-of-a-vm.aspx) for more helpful information.